# detect mask fill as3

Tags: actionscript-3, mask, fill

how to detect if my mask is filled about 90%? here is my drawing code.

```
var my_shape:Sprite = new Sprite();
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(shida.width, shida.height);
bitmapData.draw(shida);
shidaq.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, draw);
function draw(e:MouseEvent):void {
    addChild(my_shape);
    my_shape.mask = shida;
    my_shape.graphics.beginFill(0xA7A9AC,1);
    my_shape.graphics.drawCircle(mouseX, mouseY, 40);
    my_shape.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if the area was 100% painted in as3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353242/how-to-detect-if-the-area-was-100-painted-in-as3)

Comment: You may try using the solution described in the linked question, of course you will have to adapt it to your code first.