# Flash erase image with mask - gotoandplay next frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mask

This post was orginally posted on flashkit.com, but their forum is kinda dead and no one answered this question after 15 months. So I'm giving it a try here. I'm not a hardcore programmer and searched for a good solution on the web, but I can't seem to find any.

There is a piece of code for erasing a mask with mouse in AS3 which works perfectly. However, I need to detect if the whole image above is completely erased (the mask) and if so, an action will take place such as "gotoAndplay(2)"

Any idea how I to achive this?

http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2009/05/24/erase-an-image-using-your-mouse-in-as3/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if the area was 100% painted in as3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353242/how-to-detect-if-the-area-was-100-painted-in-as3)

Comment: Use the technique described in the linked question's answers in the reversal mode (you need to have 0% of the area painted instead of 100%).